# Installing Mleap spark

Tags: apache-spark, mleap

when I use spark shell with `--packages ml.combust.mleap:mleap-spark_2.11:0.8.1`

I got the errors as below

> :::: ERRORS   unknown resolver null
>
> unknown resolver null
>
> unknown resolver null
>
> unknown resolver null
>
> :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [download failed:
>   org.scalanlp#breeze_2.11;0.13.1!breeze_2.11.jar, download failed:
>   net.sourceforge.f2j#arpack_combined_all;0.1!arpack_combined_all.jar]
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1078)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:296)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:160)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)